# Is there a verb which means *do nothing*, but uses only a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to express the following:

> Do X, and if it fails, do nothing.

For reasons that are out of scope here, I need it to be in the following form:

> Do X or do nothing.

Now while this actually reflects what I want to say, I need the *do nothing* part to be only a single word. This means that I need a verb that expresses *do nothing*, but only uses a single word. Basically, something such as:

> Do X or idle.

But "to idle" feels too weak here, as being idle is something different from explicitly doing nothing. Is there a word I might use?

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of 'wait,' stand-by,' or 'pray.' Without knowing **X** (we don't even know the number of syllables) it is not easy to help.

Comment: You could hang the 'nothing' on the first 'do': Do X or nothing

Comment: Will your readers understand that "if it fails" is implied in something like "Do X or idle"?

Comment: How about "vegetate"?

Comment: Really, we need a context here. Do what?  Build a tower, excavate earth, bake cookies?

Answer (score 6):

Both **refrain** and **abstain** are possibilities, depending on the actual context.

From Merriam-Webster:

[Refrain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refrain)

> : to keep oneself from doing, feeling, or indulging in something and especially from following a passing impulse • *refrained* from having dessert

[Abstain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstain)

> : to choose not to do or have something : to refrain deliberately and often with an effort of self-denial from an action or practice • *abstain* from drinking

Both are commonly used with the preposition *from* but they need not be.

So:

> Do X or refrain.
>   Do X or abstain.

Comment: I believe both *refrain* and *abstain* always refer to some **specific** action - whether mentioned explicitly or implicitly. You cannot use it to describe total inaction.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It depends on the specific context of the question. We know that it's a verb specific to the form *Do X or . . .* so to *refrain* or *abstain* would be *(from doing X)*. Just as people who are asked what their vote is can say *I abstain (from voting)*. Arguably, it could either apply to X or to anything at all—but I doubt somebody could refrain or abstain from breathing (for instance), so there has to be a limit to the semantics involved in this request . . .

Comment: Knowing the  context would be useful; still, OP is quite clear about wanting a single word alternative to "do nothing" - and neither *refrain* nor *abstain* mean the same thing. Whether "do nothing" extends to breathing is beside the point.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Well, what if I said, "Do nothing or *freeze*"? In order to understand if *freeze* means the same thing as *do nothing* we need to know what *do nothing* encompasses. Like breathing, there are surely many things that it *doesn't* apply to. Is it only talking about motion? Does it include having no thoughts or feelings? If I "do nothing" what *can* I do? (Surely existence is allowed.) Nothing that I have any control over? The only thing that we know for certain is that *nothing* is being contrasted with *doing X*.

Comment: My comment was aimed at what you did say. I do not intend to extend the discussion to what you might have said. I will suggest this, however: suppose OP is writing a first aid manual, and wants to say "either resuscitate or do nothing at all".

Answer (score 3):

Where the construct is a comparison between either doing something (specified) or doing nothing, you can simply use the word "not".

> Do X or **not**.

means that you either do X, or you do not do X. If an alternative is not specified then nothing is assumed.

Comment: Not doing X is not nearly the same as not doing anything.

Comment: +1 I like this answer too. (At first, I thought *or nothing* was the best fit, but it was already given in a comment—and it's not technically a verb on its own.)

Answer (score 1):

*Do X or **stop**.*

> [to cease from, leave off, or discontinue](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stop)

Many [synonyms of stop](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stop) also work, notably **halt**, if
the suspension of activity is temporary.

Note that in certain computer contexts, **sleep** may be appropriate.

In that context, your formulation is misleading, and could be rephrased as

*Failing X, stop.*

If the *or* is critical,

*Pass X, or stop.*

However, that would be more naturally stated

*Pass X, else stop.*

Answer (score 0):

Do X the action, and if it fails, desist. The 'phrase stop and desist' often appears in movies when said by a law enforcer. The words stop or desist might be appropriate. Do X and if it fails, stop; or do X and if it fails, desist.

Comment: Actually, the phrase is [cease and desist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cease_and_desist) - and it too refers to a *specific* activity.

Answer (score 0):

If an informal word is acceptable, ***chill*** fits the bill.

> Do X or ***chill***.

Macmillan:

> **4**
>
> **[chill](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/chill_1#chill_14)**
>
> or
>
> chill out
>
> [INTRANSITIVE] *INFORMAL*
>
> **to relax** and stop being angry or nervous, **or to spend time relaxing**
>
> I’m just going to ***chill*** this weekend.

Comment: Just to add nuance, this is _very_ informal and won't work in circumstances that are even slightly more formal.